# Why place a "Polygon Pour Cutout" area in PCB?

Tags: pcb

This is a front end circuit for capture signal. The signal's highest frenquency is 20 MHz.

Why place a  "Polygon Pour Cutout" area in PCB?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Less capacitance. A ground plane underneath traces adds capacitance to those traces. It can mess with sensitive circuits. Note C58 and C56 are very low capacitance and any added capacitance along the traces they are on will throw things off.

Comment: @haiwuxing you don't understand, but you accepted the answer? How do you know it's correct? I'm not saying it isn't, it's a good answer, but you still seem confused.

Comment: @Michael Although it is still a bit confused, I have learned a lot. At least in order not to increase capacitance, cutout area should also be added.